# Toyota Prius Does not Start up

Tags: toyota, prius

I have a Toyota Prius. Once I stopped the engine of the car and stood for sometime. Then I started the vehicle. But it didnot start the engine. It starts indicating all range, petrol level etc. But when I shift the gear all the meters fadeoff and automatically put into ignition mode making orange color in Power push start button. Why that happens ?

Comment: how's the engine oil level if it's low or overfull the engine will refuse to start

Comment: Did you check the power levels in the 12v battery (not the hybrid battery)? Sounds like it could be dead.

Comment: @Ben Does Prius have an oil level sensor? My RAV4 hybrid only has oil pressure sensor, but no oil level sensor.

Comment: @juhist Just a pressure sender, the no start on an overfull condition occurs when oil is sucked into the intake. Generally the Prius only takes  3.7qts of oil if you overfill it even a little bit ~4qts it's enough to cause the no start.